# Why is bolt protocol returning incorrect datetime

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm querying neo4j with a range of epoch datetimes

```
MATCH (event:Event)
WHERE 1420099200000 <= event.datetime <= 1494831600000 
RETURN event.start_date,event.datetime_mu
```

This neo4j broswer returns the correct datetime

```
event.start_date    event.datetime_mu
2017-03-30T00:00:00 1490832000000
2017-02-18T00:00:00 1487376000000
2016-12-17T00:00:00 1481932800000
2017-02-14T00:00:00 1487030400000
2017-03-16T00:00:00 1489622400000
```

On the other hand, bolt returns an array `event.datetime_mu` into an array of objects with high and low properties.

```
{
      "keys": [
        "event.start_date",
        "event.datetime_mu"
      ],
      "length": 2,
      "_fields": [
        "2017-02-18T00:00:00",
        {
          "low": 1317315584,
          "high": 346
        }
      ],
      "_fieldLookup": {
        "event.start_date": 0,
        "event.datetime_mu": 1
      }
    }
```

I'm not sure how to return or calculate the proper epoch datetime from the bolt object. `low` usually has the closest absolute value, but sometimes I get a negative integer. The same happens with range() operator as well.

Not sure if this is something I'm missing or how to calculate the proper datetime from the object. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which language are you using? Sometimes the readme for the driver has some tips on dealing with the 64-bit values represented by the high and low fields. You may also want to take a look at your language's support for Long values and see if it has means to interpret or parse what Neo4j returns.

Comment: Good to know. The bolt response I posted was from the code tab in the neo4j local browser. Typically I use the official javascript `neo4j-driver`.

Comment: try returning datetime as a string, like RETURN toString(...)

Comment: After looking through the docs I went with the string method as its flexible and converted it back. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The breakdown into low and high values is necessary to convey 64-bit numerical values.

Javascript doesn't support 64-bit Long integer types, so the driver offers some [support functions and advice to assist](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#a-note-on-numbers-and-the-integer-type).